# Improving performance of tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am using `tablelayoutpanel`in my WinForm project, it responds slowly to events. I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900099/tablelayoutpanel-responds-very-slowly-to-events?noredirect=1&lq=1) to make `tablelayoutpanel` render faster. 

In my code, all the *cells* in tablelayoutpanel are of equal size(100%), I have added a `picturebox` in each *cell* and it's *SizeMode* property to *stretch*.The number of *cells* are just 9 and when i resize the panel it is slow.
 The code is as shown below. If i create 300 cells it takes 4 seconds to resize.

```
Void change_tableLayout(int num) //num =9
 {
     CoTableLayoutPanel ctlp = gcnew CoTableLayoutPanel(); //inherited tablelayoutpanel as described in above link
     global_ctlp.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;     
     num = Math.Sqrt(num);
     global_ctlp.Controls.Clear();
     global_ctlp.RowStyles.Clear();
     global_ctlp.ColumnCount = num;
     global_ctlp.RowCount = num;
         for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) //row cell
             {
                 RowStyle rs = gcnew RowStyle(SizeType::Percent, 50);
                 global_ctlp.RowStyles.Add(rs);
                    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) //column cell
                       {
                         global_ctlp.ColumnStyles.Add(gcnew ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
                         PictureBox pictureBox1 = gcnew PictureBox();
                         pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                         pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("image_path");
                         global_ctlp.Controls.Add(pictureBox1, i, j);
                         pictureBox1.Margin = System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
                         pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                     }
             }
     global_ctlp.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
 }
```

Can this be improved further. How do i make this faster? or Is there any better component other than `tablelayoutpanel`.

Comment: If you're trying to just add images you could use Listview

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want bigger display of pictures(and they should be of equal size hence i have given the cell size as equal) LIstview only list the filenames.

Comment: Not true list view can be used to add images as well. I am unsure about the size it will let you display but I am pretty sure about listview letting you add images as I have implemented the same for one of the applications I have worked on.

Comment: You will have to add an ImageList to your form and then the ListView has a property LargeImageList where in you can refer to the ImageList added. It will allow you to have images of size upto 256 X 256

Comment: Try using a DataGridView and the CellPaint event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableLayoutPanel responds very slowly to events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900099/tablelayoutpanel-responds-very-slowly-to-events)